# Javascript split does not work

Tags: javascript

I need split to this data.

I have a string value like this

```
 var str = "[:en]tomato[:ml]തക്കാളി[:]";
```

I need below output

```
 tomato,തക്കാളി.
```

I try to this

```
 var res = str.split("[:en]");
  console.log("values",res)
```

The values has been does not split .

Here is my output

```
[:en]tomato[:ml]തക്കാളി[:]
```

Comment: Read again (carefully) your input string and what you pass to the `split`.

Comment: It’s working as expected: it yields `["", "tomato[:ml]തക്കാളി[:]"]`. It’s unclear why you expect `["tomato", "തക്കാളി"]` or anything similar.

Comment: how do you imagine the `split` to know that you do not want `[:m1], [:]` inside when you only spit by `[:en]`?

Comment: **Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-in-future**.

Comment: What result you expecting to show? It seems you code working perfectly to me.

Comment: *"Here is my output"* In addition to everything else: No, that is not the output of what you've shown, in at least *three* different ways. The output of what you've shown is `values ["", "tomato[:ml]തക്കാളി[:]"]`.

Comment: Why not just use an object like `var obj = {en: "tomato", ml: "തക്കാളി"};`, then extracting `obj[en]`, rather than cramming everything into a single string? Even if you had `["tomato", "തക്കാളി"]`, how would you immediately know that the first element is the `[:en]` string, and the second one the `[:ml]` string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var str = "[:en]tomato[:ml]തക്കാളി[:]";    

str.split(/\[[:\w\s\d]*\]/).filter(function(data){
    if(data != "") 
        return data;
});

//["tomato", "തക്കാളി"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the [Regexp split function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/@@split):

```js
var str = "[:en]tomato[:ml]തക്കാളി[:]";
var res = str.split(/\[:[a-z]*\]/);
alert(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

It is working as expected, consider the following example.

When you split the string based on ',' we will get the following output.

```
var str = ",1,2,3";
var res = str.split(",");
console.log(res)


["", "1", "2", "3"]
```

Similarly, you are trying to split using [:en] so it is getting split into two different words.

Answer (score -1):

You are splitting with the wrong string.
You want to split with "[:ml]".
And the other 2 strings at the start and end, you want to be removed before the split part:

```js
var str = "[:en]tomato[:ml]തക്കാളി[:]";
var str = str.replace('[:en]','');
var str = str.replace('[:]','');
var res = str.split("[:ml]");
console.log("values",res)
```